# Magento - automate checkout - order creation

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on the checkout automation on Magento shop.

Is there anyway I can process the order automatically and process payment through the /onepage/checkout page?

I mean, use default payment, use default shipping and other, get items from the users checkout and process them.

At the moment I'm processing it through javascript, but it can take up to 40-50 seconds.

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: do you mean create an order manually in PHP? or do you mean create an observer to process the items one they are purchased?

Comment: You want one click checkout..m i right?

Comment: I mean one click checkout

Something like:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

This seems to be working, but not properly, as is not displaying any errors, and not creating order at all.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7, perfect system would be if user goes into checkout clicks, checkout/buy now button and order is processed, so she/he doesn't have to select shipping, payment method as it will be saved credit card and shipping is automatically counted.

Comment: it's a difficult process that involves changing the onepage checkout javascript and php code, but it is doable.